# Does there exist a formula to find the coefficients of this parabola?

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

For equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$, assume I know the value of the coefficient $a$, I know the value of $y$ at the parabola's vertex (though I do not yet know the $x$ at that point), and I am given a point $(x_z, y_z)$ somewhere on the parabola, though I do not have further information about this point, such as slope at the point, nor do I know if this point's location relative to the vertex is consistent from evaluation to evaluation.

How can I find the coefficients $b$ and $c$, given only this information? If not possible, is there information I might be able to gather about my parabola, in order to be able to find the coefficients $b$ and $c$?

This happens to be work I am doing for a client, but you are welcome to answer it as homework and teach me instead of giving me the answer, if it is trivial and I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: `though I do not yet know the x at that point` You do know that $x=-b/2a$, though, so that's one equation. You get one more from the next condition  Then solve the system for $b,c$.

Comment: I think the easiest way to work with this type of problems is to complete a square and look for a parabola in the from $y=a(x+b/2a)^2+c$. This way you immediately know $c$ because that's $y$ of the vertex and you only need to find $b$ using the second point.

Comment: @dxiv I am sure you are right, but I am not seeing it, please help me. In $x=-b/2a$, my 2 unknowns are x and b. In $y_z=ax_z^2+bx_z+c$ the 2 unknowns are b and c. Don't I need a third equation, for 3 unknowns? What am I missing?

Comment: @CWilson `my 2 unknowns are x and b` No, $\,y_{vertex}=a(-b/2a)^2+b(-b/2a)+c\,$ has the unknowns $\,b, c\,$.

Comment: @Vasya I don't understand how I can know that $c$ is equal to $k$ at the vertex, when I have experience that the vertex is not at the y intercept.

Comment: @dxiv So, I think what you are saying is, I can use the identity of a parabola, to show that the y value at the vertex is equal to $-b^2/{4a}+c$. If so, then yes, my problem becomes easy to solve.

Comment: @CWilson Yes, indeed.

Comment: You don’t have enough information for a unique solution. You can get $c=y_{\text{vertex}}+b^2/4a$, but the system of equations is quadratic in $b$ and could have two solutions, corresponding to the two possible locations of the vertex. Knowing on which side of the vertex $(x_z,y_z)$ lies is one possible disambiguator.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your help, I needed to get this solved for work. I posted my solution as a thank you. If this is trivial or duplicate, please close, with my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that, at the vertex, $x_{vertex}=-b/{2a}$, I can substitute that value in my quadratic at the vertex, for the first equation in my system, resulting in $y_{vertex}=-b^2/{4a}+c$.

The next equation for my system is $y_z=ax_z^2+bx_z+c$.

Solving for c in the first equation and substituting that in the second, I am left with $y_z=ax_z^2+bx_z+y_{vertex}+b^2/{4a}$, and rearranging (for use in the quadratic equation) gives me $0={1\over4a}b^2+x_zb+(y_{vertex}+ax_z^2-y_z)$, or $b = {-x_z \pm \sqrt{x_z^2-4*{1\over4a}*(y_{vertex}+ax_z^2-y_z)} \over 2*{1\over4a}}.$

This is simplified to $b = \pm{\sqrt{4a(y_z-y_{vertex})}}-2ax_z$.

This means that $c$ equals ${{y_z+ax_z^2-x_z{\sqrt{4a(y_z-y_{vertex})}}}}-y_{vertex}\pm{y_{vertex}}$

Comment: See, if you write equation as $y=a(x+b/2a)^2+d$, $d=y_{vertex}$ because the squared part will be zero.